# Replace values in dataframe with values from another dataframe of different size

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

I have two different dataframes of different sizes. The first one only has few rows and the second has some hundreds. For the rows in the second one where some columns are the same as in the first, I want to overwrite some of the columns in the second with the values from the first.

The first dataframe is (and could potentially have more rows)

| label1 | label2 | beta1 | beta2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | 1 | 2 |

and the second is (the dashes are to indicate more rows)

| label1 | label2 | beta1 | beta2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 892 | 531 | 0.01 | 0.002 |
| 541 | 414 | 0.04 | 0.03 |
| 123 | 456 | 0.02 | 0.05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

The expected results is as below. The index of the overlapping rows could be any value (but will only appear once) in df2.

| label1 | label2 | beta1 | beta2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 892 | 531 | 0.01 | 0.002 |
| 541 | 414 | 0.04 | 0.03 |
| 123 | 456 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

because label1 and label2 are equal and the values are from the first dataframe.

I have tried to filter and replace the values in the second dataframe with

```py
df2[['beta1', 'beta2']] = df1[(df1['label1'].isin(df2['label1'])) & (df1['label2'].isin(df2['label2']))]['beta1', 'beta2'].values
```

I get the error that the indices are not of equal length and I understand that. How can I "force" it to ignore that and just replace the overlapping values? I don't know beforehand which values I have in df1 for label1 and label2 so I don't want to hardcode any values.
I guess I could brute force it and take out the values from df1 but there must be a pythonic way to do this.

Edit: this is the code I used with @Timeless solution.

```py
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'label1': [123], 'label2': [456], 
    'beta1': [1], 'beta2': [2]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'label1': [541, 123], 'label2': 
    [414, 456], 'beta1': [0.01, 0.04], 'beta2': [0.002, 
    0.03]})
    idx, cols = ["label1", "label2"], ["beta1", "beta2"]

    mask = (df2.set_index(idx).index
        .isin(df1.set_index(idx).index))
    df2.loc[mask, cols] = df1[cols]
```

Output:

```py
    print(df2)
   
        label1 label2 beta1 beta2
    0    541   414    0.01  0.002
    1    123   456    NaN   NaN
```

Edit2: this is the code I got working (cols I added because I need to update a subset of all the columns in the actual code). Not as concise  as the answers. Perhaps this can be shortened.

```py
    idx = ['label1', 'label2']
    cols = ['beta1']
    df1 = df1.set_index(idx)
    df2 = df2.set_index(idx)
    df2.update(df1[cols])
    df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you started with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), here is a similar approach (*but on the index*) with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
idx, cols = ["label1", "label2"], ["beta1", "beta2"]

m = (df2.set_index(idx).index
         .isin(df1.set_index(idx).index))
​
df2.loc[mask, cols] = df1[cols]
​
```

Output :

```
print(df2)
​​
   label1  label2  beta1  beta2
0     123     456   1.00   2.00
1     541     414   0.04   0.03
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have been more clear and said that I don't know that the index in df2 will be equal to the one in df1. E.g.  if I switch the two rows in df2, it will return NaN for beta1 and beta2.
I can't quite see it, but couldn't this solution rather easily be amended to fix that?

Comment: It's possible but I think that you need to show an input/output that describe your logic in a better way.

Comment: Please see edit. I basically just want to "loop" through all rows and check if they're in df1. If they are, the values in df2 need to be overwritten.

Comment: The code I provided should work even in the new configuration of your inputs because we use a custom index and not the default index (0, 1, 2,..). Can you show what you got after your run the code ?

Comment: It returns the following. I would also have thought that it was indifferent to where it was in the df. And I assume that either m should be mask or mask should be m.
label1  label2  beta1  beta2
0     541     414   0.01  0.002
1     123     456    NaN    NaN

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can you be more specific ? I think you should show a screenshot of how you make the code and the result you're getting.